# Prevent onClick (using ENTER) on a button after overlay shown

Tags: javascript, reactjs, button

I have a button and when I click, its shown an overlay with `width 100%`, `height 100%` and `position: absolute`.
The problem is that, after I click the button to show the overlay, I can press enter and the overlay will show again (2x times).

I need to prevent this. I have already z-index set and is still happening.

I want also to say, an overlay can be also be shown without being clicked (I have some custom functions/timers) and also there can be more than an overlay, but I don't want the user to be able to create another one when he is pressing `enter` after showing the overlay at the same button (or navigate through buttons/button focus).

I'm using Reactjs, this is the full code: https://codesandbox.io/s/pensive-phoebe-74jtej

Dashboard:

```
import React from "react";
import { useOverlay } from "./OverlayContext";

function Dashboard() {
  const { CreateOverlay } = useOverlay();

  function handleClick(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    e.stopPropagation();
    CreateOverlay("Now press ENTER and it will trigger again.");
  }

  return (
    <>
      <div>Click the button!</div>
      <button onClick={(e) => handleClick(e)}> Show overlay </button>
    </>
  );
}

export default Dashboard;
```

Overlay context:

```
import { createContext, useContext, useState } from "react";

export const OverlayContext = createContext();

export function useOverlay() {
  return useContext(OverlayContext);
}

export const OverlayProvider = ({ children }) => {
  const [overlays, setOverlays] = useState([]);

  function CreateOverlay(text) {
    return setOverlays((o) => {
      return [...o, { text }];
    });
  }

  return (
    <OverlayContext.Provider value={{ CreateOverlay }}>
      {overlays.length > 0 &&
        overlays.map((o, index) => (
          <div className="overlay" key={index}>
            {o.text}
          </div>
        ))}
      {children}
    </OverlayContext.Provider>
  );
};
```

Answer (score 2):

Pressing `enter` will trigger the button again, so you need to `blur` from the button after clicking.

```
function handleClick(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    e.stopPropagation();
    CreateOverlay("Now press ENTER and it will trigger again.");
    e.target.blur();
  }
```

[image: Edit cool-mountain-jx84o8]

Comment: while this gets to the root of the problem, it's almost certainly the wrong solution. The OP should be moving focus to something relevant to the user, which will of course blur the button as a side effect. I don't know what the OP's real situation is but usually such "overlays" are put over the rest of the page when a modal appears, in which case the focus should certainly go to the modal. This also ensures screenreaders start reading the content of whatever is relevant. If it's the overlay itself that's relevant here, focus should go to that.

Comment: I will have to do that for every button in every component that I use overlay, is there are no other solutions to lose focus? @Mina

Answer (score 0):

After some many testing and research, I've found that I can focus on a button that the overlays will have.

**Solution:**

I've just added a `button` inside the `overlay` and with a `ref` and then using `useEffect` I could make focus on that specific button which will make sense for the next user interaction which will be only on the items created inside `overlay`.

```
import { createContext, useContext, useState, useEffect, useRef } from "react";

export const OverlayContext = createContext();

export function useOverlay() {
  return useContext(OverlayContext);
}

export const OverlayProvider = ({ children }) => {
  const [overlays, setOverlays] = useState([]);
  const buttonFocusRef = useRef(null);

  function CreateOverlay(text) {
    return setOverlays((o) => {
      return [...o, { id: Math.random() * 100, text }];
    });
  }

  function DeleteOverlay(id) {
    setOverlays(overlays.filter((o) => o.id !== id));
    return;
  }

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log("[Debug] Overlays length:", overlays.length);
  }, [overlays]);

  useEffect(() => {
    if (overlays.length > 0 && buttonFocusRef !== null) {
      buttonFocusRef.current.focus();
    }
  }, [overlays, buttonFocusRef]);

  return (
    <OverlayContext.Provider value={{ CreateOverlay }}>
      {overlays.length > 0 &&
        overlays.map((o, index) => (
          <div className="overlay" key={index}>
            {o.text}
            <button
              className="btn"
              onClick={() => DeleteOverlay(o.id)}
              ref={buttonFocusRef}
            >
              Click to cancel overlay
            </button>
          </div>
        ))}
      {children}
    </OverlayContext.Provider>
  );
};
```

**Note:**
In my first post I've did not have a button in the source code, so if you have  to focus on a `div` for example, you can set the `ref` on that `div` and also you need to set `tabindex="0"` for the focus to work.